# An applet that returns different Status Words for different SELECT commands

Tags: smartcard, javacard

As far as we know, when we select an applet on the card, that applet remain the selected applet until we send another SELECT command. And each command that we send to the card (except SELECT command) goes directly to the selected applet.

I want to know, Is it possible to write an applet that have different response in different `SELECT` commands? I mean, can I write an applet with `AID=010203040506` and select it. Now when I send `00 A4 04 00 06 665544332211` it returns **APP1** and when I send `00 A4 04 00 06 112233445566` it returns **APP2**?

**Update :**
APP1 and APP2 are just two different ASCII code for some hexadecimal data! Let say it in another word. I want to return `HelloWorld` for `00 A4 04 00 06 665544332211` APDU command and return `ByeBye` for `00 A4 04 00 06 112233445566`. I mean, I want to prevent the OPEN or ... to select another Applet when I send `00 A4 04 00 LC AID`. I want to handle SELECT commands!

Comment: What exactly should an applet return when you send 00 A4 04 00 06 665544332211? Please explain what APP1 and APP2 stand for.

Comment: The question seems unclear. What do you mean by returning APP1/2. An Applet can only return byte codes.

Comment: @Shuckey APP1 and APP2 are just two different ASCII code for some hexadecimal data! Let say it in another word. I want to return `HelloWorld` for `00 A4 04 00 06 665544332211` APDU command and return `ByeBye` for `00 A4 04 00 06 112233445566`. I mean, I want to prevent the OPEN or ... to select another Applet when I send `00 A4 04 00 LC AID`. I want to handle SELECT commands!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to chapter 4.6.2 of *Java Card 3 Platform Runtime Environment Specification, Version 3.0.4, September 2011*. The spec is freely available, start searching at [Main page for Java Card documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/documentation/index.html) and you'll find it easily.

It all comes down to this:

If applet with AID 112233445566 is installed on the card and applet with AID 010203040506 is installed and selected (on any logical channel), your 00A4040006112233445566 SELECT FILE APDU (or a SELECT FILE APDU on any other logical channel for that matter) will cause the JRE to attempt applet 112233445566 selection. There is no way to prevent this selection attempt and 00A4040006112233445566 command APDU **will not** get passed to the process method of your 010203040506 applet.

Comment: So that means, APDU commands from off-card entities doesn't go directly to the selected applets? And before going to applet, checked by OPEN or Something else to not be a SELECT commands?

Comment: @TheGoodUser each APDU is first parsed by JRE, if it's a SELECT and if applet is installed, selection is attempted. Otherwise, it is forwarded to the currently selected applet as is. If applet is successfully selected, then that very same SELECT APDU is forwarded to the newly selected applet as is. RTFM :-)